# iPhone - knowing the keyboard size when it is already shown

Tags: iphone

OK, I know I can read the keyboard size using the notification **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and this

```
keybSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

but this will just be available when the keyboard shows.

but the problem is this: I have a window that has to adjust itself to a new position when the keyboard is visible and when iPhone rotates. When I rotate the iPhone both delegates method **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation** and **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** run and handle the rotation. Inside these methods I need to know the current keyboard height, so I can position the view properly. The problem is that the method fired by the  UIKeyboardWillShowNotification notification runs after the rotation was handled by the delegate methods.

The order the methods run is:

1. willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
2. didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
3. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification method

In other words, the keyboard height is just read at the end, what means both methods 1 and 2 will use the old keyboard height.

My question is: is there a way to read the keyboard height of a visible keyboard directly instead of relying in methods fired by notifications?

thanks

Comment: You could hardcode these values into your app. The keyboard height is the same on all iOS devices afaik.

Comment: @ryyst: Not necessarily. Different languages/localizations might require different sized keyboards.

Comment: @Cameron Spickert: Are you sure? I've never seen any differently-sized keyboard...

Comment: @ryyst: Even if there weren't differently-sized keyboards, Apple makes no guarantees about the keyboard size in the SDK, meaning they could change it in the future, breaking hard-coded apps.

Comment: @Cameron Spickert: That's highly unlikely though. Also, why doesn't autoresizing do the trick?

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I have exactly the same problems, especially on iOS 5, some keyboards are higher than the normal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Variant 1

You can use this code snippet to explore the view hierarchy:

```
- (void)printSubviews:(UIView *)aView {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [aView class], NSStringFromCGRect([aView frame]));
    for (UIView *view in [aView subviews]) {
        [self printSubviews:view];
    }
}


- (void)printAllViews {
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        [self printSubviews:window];
    }
}
```

You'll see that it's pretty easy to figure out the keyboard size from the values you get.

#### Variant 2

Alternatively, you can import `UIKeyboard.h` (you can find it on the internet). It includes a method to get the default keyboard size for various interface orientations. However, that would make use of private APIs, so you might want to be careful with it.

Answer (score -1):

I was having an issue with setting the content inset of a `UIScrollView` upon rotation when the keyboard was already visible, too. Here's what I worked out (and it doesn't involve any solutions that are too hacky).

The idea that your view controller subscribes to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` is correct and *is the best way to do so* — don't try to calculate the keyboard size any other way, since a) the keyboard size can be unpredictable, and b) you don't want to run the risk of using private APIs.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                          selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                          name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                          object:nil];
}
```

And here's that `keyboardWillShow` method. If you're using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` — like I am — you'll want to get the resulting keyboard size out of the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` key.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
                               doubleValue];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] 
                           CGRectValue].size;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                          statusBarOrientation];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0);

    // The gotcha is that the keyboard size as reported by
    // UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey is always reported as if the device was in
    // portrait mode. I've had to work around  that a little by setting the
    // bottom edge to the keyboard's width.
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.width, 0);
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
        self.gridScrollView.contentInset = insets;
        self.gridScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps you — again, it's totally possible and safe to use notifications to achieve what you want.